# Message flashing in flask when user entered wrong password three times

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Whenever I use this logic to flash this  message ("You have exceeded maximum no of tries") when someone tried wrong password 3 times it does not execute, I know the counter variable reassigned to 0 after every execution. How can I prevent this?

```
@app.route("/signin",methods=["POST","GET"])
def signin():
  counter=0
  if request.method=="POST":
      email=request.form.get("email")
      password=request.form.get("password")
      user=User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
      if not user:
          flash('User not found')
          return redirect(url_for('signin'))
      if not pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password,user.hash):
          flash('Incorrect password')
          return redirect(url_for('signin'))
          counter+=1
          if counter==3:
              flash('You have exceeded maximum no of tries')
              return redirect(url_for('signin'))
      login_user(user)
      return redirect(url_for('index'))
  return render_template("signin.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `counter` as session variable. Something like this:

```
@app.route("/signin",methods=["POST","GET"])
def signin():
    if 'counter' not in session:
        session['counter'] = 0
    if request.method=="POST":
       email=request.form.get("email")

    # Code skipped

     if not pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password,user.hash):
        flash('Incorrect password')
        # return redirect(url_for('signin'))
        session['counter'] = session.get('counter') + 1
        if session.get('counter')==3:
           flash('You have exceeded maximum no of tries')
           session.pop('counter', None)
           return redirect(url_for('signin'))
```

Comment: Thanks Sergay, that seems a good idea to store incorrect password attempts in database. Vlad  I have tried your code but getting this same result, counter variable reassigned to 0 everytime

Comment: There was a bug, I've commented this code. And storing temporary values in a database is a controversial idea.

Comment: Thanks vlad, That's working now. Thanks for the idea of using session, I haven't thought about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the number of login attempts in the external storage. One of the options is to use the `User` model: add a `login_attempts` integer column with zero default. Your signin handler may look like this:

```
@app.route("/signin",methods=["POST", "GET"])
def signin():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("signin.html")

    email = request.form.get("email")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if not user:
        flash("User not found")
        return redirect(url_for("signin"))
    if user.login_attempts >= 3:
        flash('You have exceeded maximum no of tries')
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
    if not pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, user.hash):
        user.login_attempts += 1
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Incorrect password')
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
    login_user(user)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: Thanks Sergay, that was really helpful.